# Step-by-step proof of principal ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Could someone go through a step-by-step proof of:

> Let $\theta:R\to S$ be a surjective ring homomorphism. Show that if every ideal of $R$ is principal, than every ideal of $S$ is also principal.

I really just have the assumptions.  Take an ideal $I$ in $S$ and show that it is principal.  Could someone help please?

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: @T.Bongers it is almost certainly a surjective homomorphism, and I have seen a question just like this all of a day ago. Unfortunately, this site has some much stuff, it is impossible to search for things (or is it?)

Comment: @IgorRivin I figured as much; I too find it really difficult to find duplicates sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

I will assume that you mean $\theta$ to be a surjective homomorphism: Consider an ideal $J \subseteq S$. Then $\theta^{-1}(J)\subseteq R$ is an ideal. Since every ideal in $R$ is principle, $$\theta^{-1}(J) = (r)$$

for some $r \in R$. Now show that $(\theta(r)) = S$.